# Does RubyMotion 2.5 solve the memory management issue?

Tags: ios, rubymotion

[RubyMotion 2.5](http://blog.rubymotion.com/post/56232015979/new-in-rubymotion-blocks-rewrite-retain-cycle) is out. Does it solve the memory management problem mentioned in the ["Why mobile web apps are slow"](http://sealedabstract.com/rants/why-mobile-web-apps-are-slow/) article?

Comment: I've read that article, and deducing from that, I'd say nobody is going to fix that bug properly/completely within a reasonable amount of time (similarly to the ARM/x86 transition mentioned in the article...)

Answer (score 2):

The [RM-3 bug](http://hipbyte.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/issue/RM-3) mentioned in the article is specifically fixed in RubyMotion 2.4. RM 2.5 introduced rewritten dynamic variable handling which fixes the other difficult-to-diagnose issues.

So, yes, I'd say the specific issues mentioned in that article have been addressed.